# Using Tensorboard to get live keras model stats while training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I how does one get some type of live progress feed in tensorboard will while a keras model is training. Like a `progress bar` stating how far the process is, the graphs showing `acc`, `val_acc`, `loss` and `val_loss` etc. but as the model is training (not only at the end). Can this be done with an auto page refresh functionality (say every 3 minutes the localhost link refreshes)?

I used the following code to run the tensorboard localhost prior to training:

```
tensorboard.main --host=localhost --port=6006 --logdir="C:\*****\logs"
```

And the following code to write the logs:

```
import time
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

RUN_NAME_DATE = "model run - {}".format(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))
logger = TensorBoard(
    log_dir='logs/{}'.format(RUN_NAME_DATE),
    write_graph=True,
    histogram_freq=2
)
```

The model is fitted using:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data = (x_validation, y_validation), epochs = 20, verbose = 1, batch_size =32, shuffle=True, callbacks=[logger])
```

However I don't get live updates. I'm not sure if these are sufficient to get live updates as I am new to tensorboard. Please assist by indicating where exactly i'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to first start the tensorboard server and point it to your logs directory. Then, when you start training, you can manually click the refresh icon which will start showing you the progress. Thereafter, every 30 seconds the progress will be updated.

Comment: It doesn't update properly, it lags on epoch training updates.